# Selma code generate

Tags: java, maven

[image]

According to the https://github.com/xebia-france/selma/blob/master/examples/pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>Selma</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <defaultOutputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/selma
                        </defaultOutputDirectory>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>fr.xebia.extras.selma.codegen.MapperProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>fr.xebia.extras</groupId>
                            <artifactId>selma-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>fr.xebia.extras</groupId>
                            <artifactId>example-common</artifactId>
                            <version>0.16-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/selma</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.xebia.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>selma-processor</artifactId>
            <version>0.15</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- This is the only real dependency you will have in your binaries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.xebia.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>selma</artifactId>
            <version>0.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I create a selma sample, but codes could not generated. And when running, there is an error

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mapper.mapper.SelmaMapperSelmaGeneratedClass`

Is there any other configuration should be added to generate codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the meaning to compile time, indeed, I should run the maven command clean install. Then the codes are generated.

Answer (score 0):

to use Selma inside eclipse without Maven, you should add both processor and api jar to the path of the annotation processor plugin. 
This should be somewhere in project settings, see plugin documentation for this purpose: https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/apt/introToAPT.php .